# How you go about troubleshooting SQL query failure?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a SQL query and it fails at times. That means that query runs fine most of the times. Once the query fails if I execute is again with some delay, it is successful in the same execution.

Please note there are no changes in the tables being used in the query in between the success and failure scenarios. They are exactly same. As mentioned below, the query joins couple of tables and the result of the query should be empty. But at times ADO throws and error.

How one goes about finding out the root cause of the problem?

I left out some of the details intentionally, since I am interested in knowing generic problem solving approach for SQL query failures.

---

Here are some details to know about any specific alternative approaches as well.

- Microsoft SQL Server 2008
- Query use joins two tables
- Query is passed from .NET through interop and a COM component deals with ADO to execute the query.
- Error info 0x80004005(-2147467259) [DBNETLIB][ConnectionOpen (Connect()).]SQL Server does not exist or access denied.

---

Update:

For this specific problem, I figured that the client runs out of available TCP ports. As per default settings 5000 ports are the max number of TCP ports. In my case, ADO creates implicit connections, which create TCP port every time a query is made.

`netstat` showed me that the number of ports open dramatically increased when I ran the workflow. At around 4000 ports the query fails (0-1023 are reserved ports). Answer from Jibcov Dobrev in [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqldataaccess/thread/23b826c9-ad26-44db-9ab1-75c155f98af7) pointed me to the right direction.

Comment: By "failure" do you mean "it returns the wrong data" or "it returns an error message instead of any data"?

Comment: -1 - Most likely a deadlock issue or a lock related timeout. Sadly the OP does it funny make us guess and does not care to get an answer - otherwise he would provide the error message. Downvoted as incomplete.

Comment: @Mark Bannister: The result of the query is empty which is correct, but I get a bad HRESULT from ADO 0x80004005(-2147467259) [DBNETLIB][ConnectionOpen (Connect()).]SQL Server does not exist or access denied.

Comment: @TomTom: why would a person bother to write a question, if he is not interested in the answer? I didn't provide the error message because I wanted to know what is the generic approach to such sort of problems; an error message would lead to 'you just need to do this to address this problem' which is not what i wanted here.

Comment: As more people asked for additional details, I have updated the question with more info.

Comment: @ragu.pattabi: I have updated my answer with more specific information, following your update to the question. (The error message in question appears to indicate that the fault does not lie with the query itself, but with the user's connection to the database.)

Comment: Dont forget to mark answer as accepted if you got the info you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A "generic problem solving approach" for SQL query failures is the same as any other code failure:

- Identify what it **is** doing.
- Identify what it **should be** doing.
- Identify **why** it is different.
- Fix it.

EDIT:
Following more specific information being provided, the following microsoft knowledgebase article: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/328306 discusses the possible causes and ways of resolving this issue.

Comment: Thanks. I will give a closer look at the details.

Answer (score 3):

Read the error message!

A query will only "fail" for a few reasons really:

- unique or check or other constraint violation
- datatype issue (mismatch, overflow)
- ???

Incorrect or contradictory aggregates or syntax will be picked up at parse time. But...

- with dynamic SQL then it could "fail" because it's syntactically wrong

It could be slow or give wrong data but this is not a "fail" as such.

Edit:

This is not a query error: it's a connection error unrelated to any SQL command.

Generally, you now need to decide if it's related to one client or is a general problem

Comment: you are right. it is not a query failure. it is connection error. thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

The 'potential causes' KB article omits the one that solved it for me - "you cannot access a SQL Server database by using the OLE DB provider for SQL Server when your application is in a high-stress scenario" http://support.microsoft.com/kb/907264

In this situation - the process runs for a little while, retrieving data OK, before failing with the error.

Running 'netstat -an' will show all ips/ ports open while a process is running.  For me these sit at 20 or so until a certain block of code is reached... then quickly rise to 4000+ and the application fails

Comment: This is exactly what happened to me in this particular case. Ran out of port limit. For security reasons, windows limits it (5000). I have used client side recordset which was suitable and solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can:

Run sql profiler to capture the query, make sure query is well formed. You can leave the trace running for as long as you like.

Run the captured query in management studio, sql server will throw out any errors it encounters.

if that still doesn't help maybe split the query into multi step stored procedure.. logging values/parameters etc states in a table/log file before each step.. so that you can identify some common factors whenever it fails.

Maybe even log the constructed query and outcome in a log file from .net, and compare difference in queries.

Depending on how you set up your data connection visual studio also allows facilty to step through stored procedures.

Comment: That would be the approach if there are some issues with the particular query all the time; but my query is successful most of the times and intermittently it fails. Wondering about how to trouble shoot these kind of problems.

Comment: Is the query always identical? or can parameters with in it change? if they can you need to capture the failed query.. some how log it. if it doesn't change then its the environment that's causing it whether that's records being locked in the DB, drop in db connection, time out cause of the server being busy etc. be more difficult to isolate.. maybe a run a trace and see if you can spot the failed query and compare it to server stats. You need to isolate parameters around the query.

Comment: Yes it is on the difficult side of it. It is the environmental. It is parameterized query though. But i concluded that the failure is not specific to any specific values.

Answer (score 0):

Specific to

> 0x80004005(-2147467259) [DBNETLIB][ConnectionOpen (Connect()).]SQL Server does not exist or access denied.

this seems to be a good starting place for investigation: [Potential causes of the "SQL Server does not exist or access denied" error message](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/328306)